# Can't compile SCSS inside of WebStorm

Tags: sass, webstorm

I'm using node-sass for compiling scss files to css inside of WebStorm.

These are my settings inside my directory.

Program:

```
/usr/local/bin/node-sass
```

Arguments:

```
--output $ProjectFileDir$/css/ --compile --map $FileName$
```

Output Paths to refresh:

```
$ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.map
```

I want the css file to be written in a css directory under root. 
However this is the compilation error I get of the WebStorm

```
/usr/local/bin/node-sass --output /Users/melissa/Dropbox/codepen/sample/core-fe/css/ --compile --map styles.scss
path.js:28
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
    ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.extname (path.js:1471:5)
    at getOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass:186:40)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass:368:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: TBH: no idea. My node-sass (running it on Windows) does not show `--compile` or `--map` as possible options (installed via npm; node-sass v4.7.2 (Wrapper; JavaScript); libsass v3.5.0.beta.2). I'm using this for "Arguments": `--source-map true --output . $FileName$` and `$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map` for "Output paths to refresh" fields (compiled file gets placed into teh same folder next to the source).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither `--compile` nor `--map` are listed among available options at https://github.com/sass/node-sass#command-line-interface.

The following settings work fine for me when using the most recent node-sass version (4.7.2):

```
Arguments: $FileName$ --source-map=true -o $ProjectFileDir$/css
Output Paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map
Working directory: $FileDir$
```

Answer (score 0):

to anyone facing the same issue and the above answer didn't work with your sass version or if you are using Dart Sass try omitting this part of the argument 
 `--source-map=true -o`
and format the macros like so:

```
Arguments: $FileName$:$ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
Output Paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map
Working directory: $FileDir$
```